# How to get the interrupt time (timestamp) in kernel mode of real time Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, timestamp, embedded-linux, ftrace

Client/server communication - client is sender and server is receiver.

When the server receives the data on the ethernet interface(UDP) the kernel in the server is triggered. I am using real time LINUX on the server side. Server (i.e. embedded pc target) is handling interrupts to trigger the embedded pc target (containing rt Linux) to gain the attention to execute the newly arrived data.

How can I calculate the time in kernel as soon as the interrupt occurs and send the response back to the client?

Comment: Are you up for modifying kernel source?

Comment: I am planning to use ftrace for debugging the kernel!!! real time operations takes place in the kernel mode of rt linux, so i cant write a ISR in user space to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you are using an embedded linux platform, you can refer to CPU datasheet: maybe it have a set of high-speed timers. At instance, I'm using SoC based on ARM Cortex A8, it has GP timers that can be clocked up to 38.4 MHz, so I can measure execution time with ~27ns precision. Very likely, your OS would not provide such API, so you're welcome to read-write CPU registers directly from kernel driver.

2) If you are want to just estimate execution time, and nothing more, you can use one of GPIO pins of your board. Set pin up at "start", set down at "end", then watch this pin by oscilloscope, if you have one.

3) If I missunderstood you, and all that you need is timestamp of a real time (like HH:mm:ss), you can refer to RTC chip of your board. Using driver of real-time clock chip, you can read time from your kernel module. Unfortunately, you might not be able do it from interrupt service routine.
Or just call **do_gettimeofday** and convert timeval to something human-readable via **time_to_tm**, if needed :)

Comment: when the server receives the data (Real time linux on emebedded pc target) from the client then the kernel (server) stops the current execution and switch to the newly arrived. I want to the timestamp at which the kernel is pre-empted and the timestamp at which the kernel starts execution. How to get the time of kernel ??

Comment: I use clock_gettime to get the timestamp but where to call this in the kernel to get the timestamp ??

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot guide you to the sprecific line of source code to place your timestamp: you should look into source code of ethernet chip driver, find ISR and other function that you need. Then print obtained values to console, or save into sysfs, or implement your own interface for access from userspace or another driver.